# ng-country-select placeholder not showing

Tags: angularjs

In an Angular template, I am using the [ng-country-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-country-select) package to make drop down of ISO-3166 country codes. The only problem I can see is that the placeholder text is not displaying as expected.

The relevant code:

```
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="field-holder">
                    <country-select class="form-control"
                    cs-priorities="US,ES,GB,IT,CZ,DE,FR"
                    name="country" validate-on="dirty"
                    ng-model = "contact.country_code"
                    required-message="'Please select country.'"
                    placeholder="Country"
                    cs-required
                    required>
                    </country-select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[See this Plunker I've created for this question.](http://plnkr.co/edit/CWzWS5qezv42dCLNWoG9?p=preview)

**Output**

[image: Output]

In your linked js file `angular-country-select.js` [(GIT source)](https://github.com/navinpeiris/ng-country-select/blob/master/dist/ng-country-select.js#LC767) line number `#767`

change this line:

```
template: '<select ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in countries"> <option value="" ng-if="isSelectionOptional"></option> </select>',
```

to

```
template: '<select ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in countries"> <option value="" disabled selected>Please select country</option><option value="" ng-if="isSelectionOptional"></option> </select>',
```

Comment: This does work. I was hoping there was some way to override within my html so I don't have to worry about this if I do a fresh bower install or something. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Vincent, I've looked at the `js` file provided on github and the actual logic is written only in the last few lines and is very brief. I looked at it and found no support for placeholder that's provided so my advice is that you will have to go inside the code to do it.